# When cloning a VMware Virtual Machine, how can I prevent MAC address & UUID conflicts?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-fusion

I've run into the following problem on both VMware Fusion (for Macs) and with VMware ESXi/vSphere. Many of you are familiar with the problem, and it is described at VMware KB: "[Networking does not work in a cloned Linux virtual machine (2002767)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2002767) ."

1. Create a CentOS VM.

   - This is a bare-bones VM with a minimal set of software and a functioning network stack. The idea is that we take the minimal VM, clone it and add more software later.
2. Clone that VM
3. VMware Fusion or vCenter will assign a new MAC address to the network interface on the cloned VM.
4. Linux doesn't know about this new MAC address and thus networking doesn't work. The file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethN` has the MAC address of the interface on the first machine.
5. To fix this, I need to find the MAC address of the new VM, edit `ifcfg-ethN` and add this MAC to the `HWADDR=` field. I can't simply cut and paste the MAC into the field, so this can be an error-prone task, especially if I forget my pen and paper to write down the MAC.
6. (Bonus points) On the new VM, often eth0, eth1, etc. display in the wrong order. Fixing this involves an [arcane dance around `/etc/udev/rules.d`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/vmware-linux-lost-eth0-after-cloning-image.html)

I can do this, but it's error prone and kind of a pain when I simply wanted to spin up a new VM to test something.

Is there a way to simplify this manual process? When you clone a new machine, how do you fix the MAC address problem?

Comment: For these systems, do you care about keeping the device persistence stuff at all?

Comment: No not for the network interface.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since device persistence stuff is just getting in the way for these VMs, rip it out:

- Completely remove the `HWADDR` and `UUID` lines from the `ifcfg` file, and
- Delete `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` before cloning

That should let the eth0 with a new MAC address actually use the `ifcfg-eth0` on initial boot.

Comment: Hm, this seems to work. I had no idea `HWADDR` was optional. Should I also remove the UUID?

Comment: @StefanLasiewski Ahh, yes, you should.

Comment: +1 worked like charm J

Comment: out of top 10 google results, this is the one that works! note: remove the `HWADDR` AND `UUID` lines from `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`